# Modules not loaded at boot time

Tags: gpio, display, ubuntu, modules

I am currently using Ubuntu 15.10 server (RPi optimized edition) on my RPi2 B. I also bought a display, as suggested in another question. I got the display working by hand, namely activating SPI and I2C with `raspi-config` and loading the proper modules with modprobe:

```
sudo modprobe flexfb  width=320  height=480  regwidth=16 init=-1,0xb0,0x0 [...]
sudo modprobe fbtft_device debug=3 rotate=90 name=flexfb speed=16000000 gpios=reset:25 [...]
```

But this doesn't work, when the lines (without `sudo modprobe` of course) are written into `/etc/modules` and the RPi is rebooted.

I also modified the `/boot/config.txt` by adding the following line: 
`dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=4,extpullup=1`

I also went through the `/etc/modprobe.d` directory and the blacklist files residing there, to see if any modules I need are blacklistet. But none needed modules are.

So, after reboot, the display remains white and `lsmod` doesn't show any modules I would need:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
i2c_bcm2708             5006  0
spi_bcm2708             7670  0
w1_gpio                 3465  0
wire                   25632  1 w1_gpio
cn                      4656  1 wire
uio_pdrv_genirq         2958  0
uio                     8215  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
bcm2708_rng              972  0
snd_bcm2835            19761  0
snd_pcm                74449  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              18197  1 snd_pcm
snd                    51646  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
i2c_dev                 6059  0
ipv6                  335227  18
```

Is there anything I missed?
Or do I have to load the modules by hand every time I boot the raspberry?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I see the following `lsmod` output, after manually calling `sudo modprobe`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
fbtft_device           27245  0
flexfb                 12647  1
fbtft                  27780  2 flexfb,fbtft_device
fb_sys_fops             1141  1 fbtft
syscopyarea             2781  1 fbtft
sysfillrect             3305  1 fbtft
sysimgblt               1829  1 fbtft
w1_gpio                 3465  0
wire                   25632  1 w1_gpio
cn                      4656  1 wire
uio_pdrv_genirq         2958  0
uio                     8215  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
bcm2708_rng              972  0
i2c_dev                 6059  0
i2c_bcm2708             5006  0
spi_bcm2708             7670  0
snd_bcm2835            19761  0
snd_pcm                74449  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_timer              18197  1 snd_pcm
snd                    51646  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm
ipv6                  335227  18
```

**UPDATE**

I found out, that if I write just the modules (flexfb, fbtft_device) into `/etc/modules`, they load. Apparently the parameters I provide break something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after messing around for a few evenings, the final clue was the following:

`/etc/modules` just contains the modules to load (flexfb,fbtft_device), without options/parameters. Those have to be stated in `/etc/modprobe.d/`. For each module, a file ending with `.conf` and containing the options as stated above, beginning with the keyword `options`.

Comment: I am having similar issue - hoping this will work; will post back